# Custom number format is gone after updating cells

Tags: java, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I'm using Java API of Google Spreadsheets to modify the value of a cell in a spreadsheet. Doing it this way:

```
CellEntry cell = ...
cell.changeInputValueLocal(newInputValue);
cell.update();
```

My problem is that the cell has a custom number format (`# ###0 "colli"`), and it's gone after I write the cell programmatically. I want to write a number into the cell (200). The cell's number format is set to "Automatic" after this operation.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is a list of issues - but does not look like anyone is working on the google-spreadsheet-api